# How to Access the modified StringBuilder in the original method which passed it

Tags: java, recursion, stringbuilder, mutability

My question is fairly simple and I will post code below:
I want to create a StringBuilder called results in one method, say method 1, which is passed to another method, say method 2. Method 2 however is RECURSIVE and returns void. I want to access the StringBuilder that has been modified by method 2, INSIDE of method 1. However as expected, I only get the original value of the StringBuilder... how do I get the new modified value? As I understand it, StringBuilder is mutable is it not?

```
public String dFSearch(PathExtremities pE)
{
    for (int i = 0;i < vertices.length;i++)
    {
        vertices[i].reset();
    }
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    stack.push(vertices[pE.getStart()].visit());
    StringBuilder results = new StringBuilder();
    results.append(pE.getStart() + ",\t");
    dFSearch(pE.getEnd(),stack,results);
    if ('\t' == results.charAt(results.length() - 1));
    {
        results = new StringBuilder();
        results.append(Integer.toString(pE.getStart()) + ",\t-1,\t" + Integer.toString(pE.getEnd()));
    }
    String rslts = results.toString();
    return rslts;
}

private void dFSearch(int end,Stack<Integer> stack,StringBuilder results)
{
    if(stack.empty())   {return;}

    int current = stack.peek();
    int currentSmallest = ARBITRARY_LARGE;
    for (int i = 0;i < adjacency[0].length;i++)
    {   
        if(adjacency[current][i] == 1 && i < currentSmallest && !vertices[i].hasBeenVisited())
        {
            currentSmallest = i;
        }
    }
    if(currentSmallest == ARBITRARY_LARGE)
    {
        stack.pop();
        dFSearch(end,stack,results);
    } else
    {
        if(currentSmallest == end)
        {
            results.append(Integer.toString(currentSmallest));
            stack.removeAllElements();
        } else
        {   
            results.append(currentSmallest + ",\t");
            stack.push(vertices[currentSmallest].visit());
        }
        dFSearch(end,stack,results);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) It is mutable, and you append to it in method 2 but only under some conditions.
Make sure these conditions are met. Probably method 2 never goes to that part
which appends something to your `StringBuilder` which you passed in.

2) After calling method 2 (in method 1), make sure you don't do
`results = new StringBuilder();` as you do now. This way you
abandon the value you piled up in method 2 as you're creating a new object.
I see you do that again under some condition but I am not sure if it's intended.